# Jenkins pipeline: How to read an ini file with sections

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, ini

Could someone point me to any reference for reading values in an ini file with sections. Here is an example of the ini file

```
example.ini

[ section1 ]
   [[ section 1a ]]
      key=value1
   [[ section 2a ]]
      key=value2
[ section 2 ]
   [[ section 1a ]]
      key=value1
   [[ section 2a ]]
      key=value2
```

Hopefully there is something on the lines of:

```
x = readFile "example.ini"
print x.section1."section 1a".key
```

An option is to convert the ini to json/properties - and then read that - any pointers to such a freeware conversion utility (windows/ubuntu) might also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a simple python script using configobj that is called from the pipeline, posting sample here:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

def convertIni2Properties(conf, sectionPrefix=''):
    if not conf.sections:
        for scalar in conf.scalars:
            print "%s.%s = %s\n" % (sectionPrefix, scalar, conf[('%s' % scalar)]))
    for section in conf.sections:
        convertIni2Properties(conf['%s' % section], '%s.%s' % (sectionPrefix, section))

conf = ConfigObj('myfile.ini')
convertIni2Properties(conf)
```

My ini file is a few hundred lines and using recursive calling works, didn't bother about changing it to iterative.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunetly you have to write your own parser for this reason, though it is not that hard task to acomplish , but it is as it is.

and cause in pipeline you can use groovy and create methods, that will be easy to achieve